# Computing bottom $k$-eigenspace of a matrix via top $k$-eigenspace of another matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $R$ be a full rank, symmetric matrix. Suppose one wants to compute the space spanned by the bottom $k$ eigenvectors of $R$. Of course one could compute the eigendecomposition of $R$ directly.

My question: is there a matrix $S$ such that computing the top $k$-eigenspace of $S$ is the same as computing the bottom $k$-eigenspace of $R$, *such that the computation is more efficient than computing all the eigenvectors or computing the inverse*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try $S = a I - R^2$ for any $a > \lambda_{max}^2$, where $\lambda_{max}$ is the leading eigenvalue of $R$. That'll work because the eigenvectors of $S$ are exactly the same as $R$. It's useful to realize that if $R v = \lambda v$, then $S v = (a - \lambda^2) v$.

Comment: Why should the bottom eigenvectors of $R$ be the same here as the bottom eigenvectors of $S$?

Comment: Just do a quick direct computation. If $v$ is an eigenvector of $R$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $Rv = \lambda v$, so $S v = (a - \lambda^2) v$. Hence, $v$ is an eigenvector of $S$ with eigenvalue $a - \lambda^2$. Now suppose $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ are the eigenvectors of $R$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ where $|\lambda_1|\le|\lambda_2|\le\cdots\le|\lambda_n|$. Then $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ are the eigenvectors of $R$ with corresponding eigenvalues $a-\lambda_1^2\ge a-\lambda_2^2\ge\cdots\ge a-\lambda_n^2$>0. Do you see how the order of the eigenvalues is reversed?

Comment: (continued) The bottom eigenvectors of $R$ are $v_1,\ldots,v_k$. These are the top eigenvectors of $S$.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. The question is a bit strange. You did not put any restriction on matrix $S$.
So $S$ can be $-R$ or $R^{-1}$ or any linear combination of such matrices with $I$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. You are right. I have modified the question to reflect my real wish, which is a matrix that is less expensive to compute than the full eigendecomposition or inverse.

Comment: In discussing "top" and "bottom" eigenvalues, I assume eigenvalues are ordered *by absolute value*. (Most discussions I've seen are interested in such an ordering.) @EricGregor, are you interested in such an ordering? In this case, $-R$ doesn't work: the order of the eigenvalues is unchanged. But $R^{-1}$ does, if $R$ is invertible.

Comment: Yes, Will, I am indeed considering the absolute values of the eigenvalues.

The problem with the inverse is that it is about as expensive as the full eigendecomposition.